# Problematic step in proof of Bezout's Identity (Hamkins' textbook)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to follow a proof of Bezout's Identity in JD Hamkins' Proof And The Art of Mathematics. Attached is a photo of the relevant section of text.

**The step I don't understand is "it follows that $r$ must be $0$".**

I understand that $r<d$. I understand that $d$ is the smallest positive integer expressible as an integer linear combination of $a$ and $b$.

This means $d$ could be, for example, 2, 3, 4, or 11. Therefore $r<d$ does not imply $r=0$.

The only way $r=0$ is implied by $r<d$ is if $d=1$, which is not proven at this point in the provided text.

---

[image]

Comment: It is assumed, from the very beggining, that $d$ is the smallest possitive number that achieves the linear combination. The proof states thar $r$ is smaller than $d$ and also is written as a linear combination. But $d$ is the smallest possitive number. So $r$ exists, but can't be possitive. Hence...

Comment: hi @FormerMath - thanks for trying to help me. I read assumption that $d$ is the smallest positive integer that achieves the linear combination. That could mean $d=2$ or $d=9292$ as the smallest value. These don't restrict $r$ to be zero. Sorry, I am struggling to understand this.

Comment: Please do not use images to convey information that is not otherwise available in your post. [See here for an explanation of why this is bad practice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You understand that $d$ is the smallest **positive** integer expressible as an integer linear combination of $a$ and $b$. But $r$ is a smaller integer expressible as an integer linear combination of $a$ and $b$, since $r<d$. So $r$ cannot be **positive**. Since also $r\geq0$, the only possible value for $r$ to take  is $0$.

Comment: hi @john-bentin, for any given $a$ and $b$, the value of $d$, even when it is the smallest possible as a result of carefully choosing $x$ and $y$, can be more than 1. Thus $r<d$ doesn't imply $r=0$. What am I missing? For example, a particular combination of $a$ and $b$ might result in $d$ being 7, with no smaller value possible.

Comment: @Penelope What you're missing is that $r$ is an integer linear combination of $a$ and $b$. Among such combinations, $d$ is the smallest positive one (no matter how big $d$ might be). And, again among such combinations, $r$ is a smaller one than $d$. So $r$ must not be positive.

Comment: hi @AndreasBlass - bingo! That was the key to my understanding. Also this explanation explains it better than the text in the book, https://www.expii.com/t/bezouts-identity-on-linear-combinations-3397